# Getting POST value from Dropbox Chooser without using formhelper Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, mapping

Having trouble mapping input from my form to the correct fields in the corresponding table currently I get only blank fields when it is inserting into the database. There are no errors popping up but cake doesn't seem where to know where to put the data.

```
<?php

class UserfilesController extends AppController {



  public function index(){
    $this->set('userfiles', $this->Userfile->find('all'));
}

  public function latest() {
    if (empty($this->request->params['requested'])) {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }
    return $this->Userfile->find('all', array('order' => 'Userfile.created DESC', 'limit' => 10));
}

  public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Userfile->create();
        if ($this->Userfile->save($this->request)) {
            $this->render('/homes');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something went wrong!'));
        }
    }
}

/*public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        print_r($this->request);
    }
}*/

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
if ($this->Userfile->save($this->request)) {
```

You really should read the very basics about s[aving data in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html). First paragraph, first code block there. It is always good to have a read about something *before* implementing it.

You try to save the whole request object (its array representation) instead of only the post data from request->data. Check the link I've provided. The post data must match what the save() expects.

Comment: Storing the db link from the form. Still not able to store the rest of  the data passed from db (thumbnail, bytes, etc...) but  atleast now I have something to work off of. Thanks!